# Can't redirect stderr to a file

Tags: bash, shell, debian, stdout, stderr

I have a oneliner that inevitably generates some errors that I want to ignore, so i'm trying to redirect it to a file, but it keeps appearing on the screen. This is how it looks like :

```
command1 | command2 | command3 1> stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt
```

I also tried sending them both to the same file(with &>), but stderr just doesn't want to and it's very frustrating.

Comment: Do your commands write errors to stderr?

Comment: I didn't know I had to add the redirection after every command. I tought they were all "gathered" on the way through the pipes. It works now. If you could post this as an answer so I can give you some "real" credit, that would be great. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect stderr for each stage of your pipeline.  You can do this as follows:

```
command1 2>&1 | command 2
```

or (at least with bash):

```
 command1 |& command2
```

(See the pipelines section of the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)).

Answer (score 2):

The `stderr` file descriptor does not go through the pipe, only `stdout`. You can try that by

```
commandThatDoesNotExist | less
```

You'll see nothing in `less`, but the error will be written on the terminal. To pipe the `stderr` file descriptor, redirect it to where `stdout` points

```
commandThatDoesNotExist 2>&1 | less
```

Now you see the error in `less`.

In order to have no `stderr` on the terminal, you have to redirect the file descriptor of every command to your `stderr` file:

```
command 1 2>stderr.txt | command 2 2>stderr.txt | command 3 2>stderr.txt 1>stdout.txt
```